# convert ‘double*’ to ‘boost::any*’

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

I have a variable `boost::any*` items. My requirement is to:

assign items with list of values which can be of type int,double or any other datatype. But at a given time the data-type will be unique.

The issue:

For single values i can assign using items[index] = value; But if i do item = values; where values is a double array it cannot automatically cast. Also if i use

```
items = boost::any_cast<boost::any*>(values)
```

I receive 'boost::bad_any_cast': failed conversion using 'boost::any_cast`.

Some hints will be really great about how can i cast a double array to `boost::any` array.

Comment: One more update, if i use 
items = reinterpret_cast<boost::any*>(values);
the program runs and i can also assign the values. 

But
boost::any_cast<double>(this->entries[_index]) 
gives an error for bad cast from boost. So i am not able to retreive the values back.

Answer (score 1):

It just can't work. In a `double[]`, the doubles are contiguous. There's no space between two doubles. Roughly the same applies for a `boost::any[]` : there's no space between two `any` objects. But there IS space between the two doubles stored inside adjacent `boost::any<>` wrappers.

You'll have to write a function.